# PHP - hard coded queries work on phpMyAdmin but not when I call the php file via browser

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP with the help of ExtJS4 to query a database based on user input for his or her log-in credentials. On the ExtJS part, I have a store, I set the extra params and call load. After loading, I check the store count to see if the query returned a value, which would determine if the user passed valid log in credentials.

I am surprisingly struggling with making this work when I simply copy pasted code from a working php from another file. At first I thought I wasn't passing the values right, but upon appending the values passed to the message, it showed that I was passing the values perfectly.

The next thing I tried was to call the php file from the browser via `localhost:8888/../../../../../readUser.php` and I made an if else block where the code would go to the else block if the log in credentials (email and password) were not supplied. In that if-else block, I hard coded the email and password to see if it would return anything. However, upon calling the php file, I still did not get anything.

Here is my `readUser.php` file:

```
<?php
require_once('../../db_mysqli.php');
require_once '../../lib/response.php';
require_once '../../lib/request.php';

class user{ 
    var $user_id;
    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;
    var $sex;
    var $birth_date;
    var $email;
    var $password;
}

$res = new Response();
$res->message = "Message Start. ";

if(isset($_GET['email'])){
    //this is the part if the email param is set    
}
else{
    $res->message.= " \n nothing received. ";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_details 
                WHERE email = 'sampleEmail@yahoo.com' AND password = '123'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
                
    $res->message.= " \n query =  ";
    $res->message.= $query;

    $res->message.= " \n result =  ";
    $res->message.= $result;
}

$query_array=array();
$i=0;

//Iterate all Select
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //Create New User instance
    $inputData = new user();
    //Fetch User Info
    $res->message.= " \n user id = ";

    $inputData->user_id=$row['user_id'];        
    $inputData->first_name=$row['first_name'];
    $inputData->last_name=$row['last_name'];
    $inputData->sex=$row['sex'];
    $inputData->birth_date['birth_date'];
    $inputData->email=$row['email'];
    $inputData->password=$row['password'];

    //Add User to ARRAY
    $query_array[$i]=$inputData;
    $i++;
}
mysql_close($con);

//Creating Json Array needed for Extjs Proxy
$res->success = true;
// $res->message = "Loaded read data";
$res->total = $total;
$res->data = $query_array;
//Printing json ARRAY
print_r($res->to_json());
?>
```

When I call this from my browser, this is what I get:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Message Start. \n nothing received. \n query = SELECT * FROM user_details \n\t\t\t\tWHERE email = 'sampleEmail@yahoo.com' AND password = '123' \n result = ","total":null,"data":[]}
```

I copied the query it used on phpMyAdmin (after removing the special/escape characters), and it returned the right row I wanted.

I also have a message part inside the while loop where I loop through the rows and append those to my result. However, that pat `$res->message.= " \n user id = ";` did not show up, and I am given the impression that my variable `$result` is null or empty that's why it's not working at all.

What can I try next?

Comment: At the place where you write email, type the variable by which you are getting email from user and same for password.

Comment: Yeah I do that, I said that in the question. The problem is that even hard coding the values in my query does not work. Kindly read the problem.

Comment: what does `var_dump($result)` show?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the right way of coding.

```
// This is the best way to perform an SQL query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user_details
    WHERE email='%s' AND password='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($email),
    mysql_real_escape_string($password));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

This is valid. So `$result` will have a resource. Check this by giving a `var_dump($result);` as the next line as @Darren mentioned.

[*Make sure that the connection is properly established before run the query.*]

Comment: I just realized that I was using mysqli and not mysql.

Comment: :D

If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead.

Comment: Yeah. Now I'm trying to figure out how to fetch arrays and send it as JSON data.